# Is there a Google PlaceId for the planet?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I cannot seem to find one anywhere. [Google Place ID docs and search](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id).
Tried search for "Earth", "Planet Earth", "Terra", and anything else I could think of.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no place ID for the planet. You can get place IDs for continents (e.g. Europe) or colloquial areas (e.g. Eurasia), but not for entire planet.

Comment: I figure a planet id would only be handy in case the Places API also has information about other planets, Which it probably hasn't. So....